# Inserting French character into Oracle gets converted into some junk characters

Tags: oracle, unicode, plsqldeveloper

Using PL/SQL Developer, I'm able to insert French character in my Oracle database without any error.

Querying:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';
```

Output: `AL16UTF16`

But when i retreive the data using select statement it get converted into some junk characters, For eg:

**système** gets converted to **systÃ¨me** and so on....

Any suggestion/workaround will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your OS? What is your locale-specific NLS characterset? it is a display issue, your client is unable to display it properly.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7. Pl/SQL Character Sets
  Character size: 4 byte(s)
  CharSetID: 873
  NCharSetID: 2000
  Unicode Support: True
  NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
  NLS_CHARACTERSET: AL32UTF8
  NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16

Comment: How are you inserting it? How are you querying it? What is the column data type? What does [`dump()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions055.htm) show is actually stored?

Comment: initially it was only english, updated to add other languages, using Update statement. Column type is SYS.XMLTYPE, dump() is showing some numeric data Typ=58 Len=118:

Comment: Looks like you saved yor sql file as UTF-8. In this case your NLS_LANG must also be UTF8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was due to different values in NLS_LANGUAGE at client and server.

At server it was: AMERICAN
use following query to read the parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters
```

At client it was: AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252

In PL/SQL Developer Help->About, click on Additional Info button and scroll down.

What i observed other thing, while trying to fix the issue:
The characters were not converting to junk characters in first update.
But when i retreive them(which contains non-ascii characters) and update again, then they are converting to junk characters.